# Is it possible to "unsend" email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to use Gmail's "unsend" ability in the Gmail Android app?

I can't find anything on it, in settings or searching.

Answer (score 5):

I presume you mean the "Undo Send" in Gmail Labs. No, you can't.

It's for that reason that I have the "Confirm before sending" turned *on*.